# why my blog can't be visited with ip address?

Tags: networking

I build wordpress on wisdom.host22.com/wp,it can be visited with `wisdom.host22.com/wp` in firefox.

[image]

```
ping wisdom.host22.com
PING wisdom.host22.com (31.170.160.189) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 31.170.160.189: icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=307 ms
```

The domain's ip address is 31.170.160.189 from the result of ping.

It can't be visited to input 31.170.160.189/wp in firefox ,why? 
When to input `31.170.160.189/wp` in firefox ,the url will jump into 
`http://error404.000webhost.com/,why?`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WordPress application is one among probably many websites hosted at `host22.com`.

There is a webserver listening on IP `31.170.160.189` and serving yours and all the other pages.

If the server is directly queried by its IP, how is it supposed to know which website to serve? The IP does not belong to your subdomain exclusively. As a result, you're being redirected to a `404 NOT FOUND` page.

When it's queried by a proper hostname like `wisdom.host22.com`, it knows what to do, because the hostname is part of the HTTP request the browser makes. To serve content depending on the request header is a common technique usually referred to as "Virtual Host". This way the webserver can provide many different websites from the same IP address.

You can try out the difference in behaviour from the command line

First, let's request the resource `/wp` from the webserver and send its IP address as `Host`:

```
$ echo -e "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1\nHost: 31.170.160.189\n" | netcat 31.170.160.189 80
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2015 09:05:30 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: http://error404.000webhost.com/?
Content-Length: 216
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

As expected the server responds by serving a `404` page.

Now do the same, but with `Host` set properly to your subdomain

```
$ echo -e "GET /wp/ HTTP/1.1\nHost: wisdom.host22.com\n" | netcat 31.170.160.189 80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 11 Oct 2015 09:08:50 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
X-Pingback: http://wisdom.host22.com/wp/xmlrpc.php
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This time, the server can comply (status code `200 OK`) and serves your WordPress homepage.

The `netcat` command opens a connection to the server on port 80. Then the request (the `echo` part) is send to the server. HTTP is a plaintext protocol. You can just "talk" to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When you send an HTTP request to a server there is a host line included in it, when apache receives this, it sends it to whatever virtual host has been defined for that address as explained here:

https://serversforhackers.com/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts

So if in the server you created there is a virtual host for wisdom.host22.com, typing the hostname will take you there but typing the ip will take you to the default virtual host, which in this case, it seems was not defined.

I hope this helped.